# How to deal with an employee who craps on the toilet?

Tags: cleanliness

We have an employee who doesn't wash his hands and now has been found to have left #2 on the bathroom toilet rim.  How do we address?

Comment: Yuck. I will just plain speak to that person, in private, to be more serious with the hygiene of the workplace.

Comment: I hate to ask for details, but is this just a bit (evidence of carelessness) or a lot (evidence of a psychological problem)?

Comment: Tell him to cut it out and if he doesn't, fire him? Or if this was some sort of bizarre protest to being asked to wash his hand just fire him outright? This would seem to fall squarely within "Management 101". What kind of advice are you looking for here? Why aren't you already enforcing consequences on his behaviour?

Comment: Final duplicate vote cast. Given the lack of detail here this reads like an exact duplicate of the linked question and that also got closed for not having a clear goal in mind. If there's some specific issue you're facing and there are elements that set this question apart from the linked one, please [edit] those in to nominate this for reopening.

Comment: The linked question is about #1 and this question is about #2, so they're not duplicates.

Answer (score 9):

If you have some kind of public line of communication for your department or office (Slack, Gmail, Skype, etc.), I would send a gentle reminder to clean up after yourself in the bathroom. No names or specifics, just a blast message that could be about anyone. There's a good chance he might not even be aware that people are noticing and the fear that you may come for him directly may be enough for him to stop.

Comment: We sometimes have communications like this at our company (most often after people leave the communal coffee areas in a mess).  There's a reminder that cleaners only visit once a day (after working hours), so people cleaning up after themselves helps keep things looking nice for employees and visitors.  Perhaps a reminder about the cleaning schedule and the need for other people to use the bathroom might be useful here...

Comment: Please no, let's not encourage more of this non-management. Everyone will know who this is about *except* the person you're trying to reach. This should be managed directly.

Comment: This is a common courtesy issue. Things only get more complicated when involving management/HR. Now if this doesn't make him stop, by all means, bring it up with HR or to him face to face. But there's no need to make a federal case out of it.

Answer (score 1):

This might warrant a write-up in the employee's HR file for creating or contributing to unhealthy or unsanitary conditions within the workplace.  It's no different than bringing one's personal issues to work, or committing a crime there because it affects the morale of everyone around.

So, get a paper trail started.

Comment: I don't know if it needs to go this far just yet. Looks like he/she has bad habits that needs to be brought up. I would agree to go this far if they tried all methods to ask him/her to be more clean and yet he/she refuses.

Answer (score 0):

The most important question is: are you in a business (e.g. food industry) where an employee not washing his hands/keeping the hygiene actually is a big problem for the certification of you plant (although i am not sure bathrooms are inspected) or the safety of the customers/consumers?

- If yes -> answer from Xavier J
- if no -> answer from Brandon Wilcox